# How to use Google App Scripts to retrieve Gmail emails in a customised way?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here's a neat javascript code I wrote to get all emails from my Gmail and put the list of sender name in a google spreadsheet.

```
function doGet()
{
  var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Atg1TJnn4dFdGbjNGSrMGJRdGc");
  var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 
  var froms = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  {
    froms.push([messages[i][0].getFrom(),i]);
  }

  mysheet.getRange(1,1,threads.length,2).setValues(froms);

}
```

It works great but there're 2 issues

1. The [GetInboxThreads](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#getInboxThreads) method only gets the first 500 emails whatever you try. The question is does someone know how to get more than 500 ? How about get the last 500 rather than the first 500 emails ?
2. It's a bit slow, although I put loads of effort to make it efficient, can someone suggest how to retrieve the sender name from the emails and put that list of sender names on a spreadsheet in a quick way ?

Comment: method getInboxThreads(start, max) allows you to page through all the threads

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer ? how can I page through all the 4000 threads I have in my gmail ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like about 10secs /100 messages this way. Can't think of anything faster in GAS.

```
function getMail(){
    var inc = 100;
    var start = 0;
    do  {
        var now = new Date();
      var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, inc);

      start += inc;
      var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(thread);
      Logger.log("# threads"+thread.length+"# of messages" + messages.length+" time :"+(new Date()-now));

      }  while (thread.length == inc);
  }
```

Comment: thanks, I know my mistake now, the reason is I thought getInboxThreads takes arguments start and max as in which thread number to start with and which thread number to end with, however it turned out to be wrong, it's which thread number to start with and how many threads we want. thanks a lot