# Copy specific text from email message to spreadsheet

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I get my checking account balance emailed to me once per day. I want to use Google Apps Script to pull the balance from the email message and plug it into my checking account spreadsheet. I am a novice to coding, but so far I have figured out how to do the following, which gets me a log of HTML code of the correct email message:

```
function myFunction() {
 var thread = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("CHK BAL").getThreads(0,1)[0]; // get first thread in inbox
 var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // get first message
 Logger.log(message.getBody()); // log contents of the body
}
```

However, because this method returns the HTML code for the email message and not the actual message text, it doesn't contain the balance number that shows up in the email itself.

I tried substituting getPlainBody in place of getBody, but it returns a null value in the Log.

The question posted here is pretty much my same question ([Google script that find text in my gmail and adds it to a spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134883/google-script-that-find-text-in-my-gmail-and-adds-it-to-a-spreadsheet)), but even with Mogsdad's reply and helpful links I haven't been able to figure out what's going wrong.

Can anyone help redirect me on how to get the email content instead of the null value?

(Once that's solved, I can't say that the link on Mogsdad's other reply is very clear about how to identify the currency and copy it into the spreadsheet, but of course I haven't been able to play around yet since I can't even access the content yet.)

Thanks!

---

EDIT 1

See Serge's answer below for instructions on how to parse the HTML. I used those functions to grab the text of the most recent Bank Account Balance email from a Gmail label/filter and drop it into a cell in my spreadsheet.

Then I was able to use the following equation in an adjacent cell to strip it down to just the currency number:

LEFT(RIGHT(A5,LEN(A5)-FIND("$",A5)),FIND(CHAR(10),RIGHT(A5,LEN(A5)-FIND("$",A5)))-1)+0

Of course, this works for me because the currency number is always preceded by $ (the first, and in my case, only $ to appear in the text) and always followed by CHAR(10). Anyone trying to apply this formula would need similar consistency before and after the value they are seeking to isolate.

Comment: I'm not sure why you called me out in this question, as I had nothing to do with [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862827/how-does-one-find-the-currency-value-in-a-string). I think you need to edit this a bit. Could you provide a redacted version of the HTML you're getting? It would be helpful to see the content and tags around the balance.

Comment: Hi Mogsdad, my apologies. I pasted in the link to the wrong post up above (in my original). I have since fixed it to be the correct post. In the meantime, Serge's reply got me where I needed to be. Thanks to both of you. I have a non-descript user name (not sure how that happened in the sign up process) but you and Serge both have answered dozens of my questions this past two weeks since I started with GAS, both through direct responses but also through many, many posted responses. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this code snippet [originally written by Corey G on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936092/remove-formatting-tags-from-string-body-of-email/11312588#11312588) to get the text from the html content.  I use it quite often and it works nicely most of the time :) (Thanks Corey)

```
function getTextFromHtml(html) {
  return getTextFromNode(Xml.parse(html, true).getElement());
}


function getTextFromNode(x) {
  switch(x.toString()) {
    case 'XmlText': return x.toXmlString();
    case 'XmlElement': return x.getNodes().map(getTextFromNode).join('');
    default: return '';
  }
}
```

And a test function to try it :

```
function test(){
  var html = GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[0].getMessages()[0].getBody();
  throw(getTextFromHtml(html));
}
```

Comment: Golden! Thanks Serge. Works beautifully. I can get the text from my email and drop it into a cell. From there I figured out how to isolate the currency value using a formula in an adjacent cell. Can't thank you enough. My setup is really cool now :) For any who would like to isolate a currency value from a bunch of text, I've edited the original post above. Thanks again Serge!

Answer (score 0):

As to why getPlainBody() is returning null, it is most likely due to a bug in Google Apps Script. The issue has been filed at https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3980.

From that thread: "It seems the messages affected contain HTML in their content. A possible workaround involves using getBody() instead of getPlainBody() and parsing through the HTML directly."