# How I can download my eMail per GoggleScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail-api

i must download a lot of eMails (ca. 1000 pieces) from my GMail-Account to our fileser and have only access per Browser.

Here is my starting-script:

```js
function myeMailExportToEML() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('Label:TestExportEML');  
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
  
  for (var i=0; i< threads.length; i++) {
    var myID = threads[i].getId();
    var mySubject = GmailApp.getMessageById(myID).getSubject();

    ??????????????????
    ??????????????????
    ??????????????????
  }
}
```

Does anyone has a tipp for me?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read all emails in gmail using google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332670/how-to-read-all-emails-in-gmail-using-google-apps-script)

Comment: What do you mean by downloading? Like serving in as a pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solve:

```js
function myExportToGoogleDrive1() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("label:TestExportEML");  
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
  Logger.log(threads)
  var messagesArray = []     
  
  var newFolder = DriveApp.createFolder("dddddddddddddddddddddd").getId();

  for (var i=0; i< threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

      for (var j=0; j< messages.length; j++) {

        var myID = messages[j].getId();
        var msg = GmailApp.getMessageById(myID);
        var msgRaw = msg.getRawContent();

        var msgBlob = Utilities.newBlob(msgRaw, 'message/rfc822', 'example.eml');
        
        var ssss = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolder).createFile(msgBlob);
        var filename = GmailApp.getMessageById(myID).getSubject();
        
        ssss.setName(filename);
      }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

To send your emails you first have to obtain each of them and convert them to a blob object with content-type “message/rfc822” (which is the mime type for .eml files)  [1]:

In your code you’re obtaining the first message of each thread, because the threadID is the same as the messageID of the first message in that thread, but if a thread has more messages (replies for example) it won’t find them. You need to use the getMessages() function [2] for each thread in order to obtain all the messages.

After you obtain the Message object, you can use getRawContent function [3] to each message in order to obtain the string of data encoded. With this string we can create a Blob object [4], which will be the .eml file.

I’m unable to tell the kind of access that you have from the file server side, this is why I have developed these two different ways to tackle your problem to download/send .eml files depending on what is most convenient for you:

To test if the .eml blob file was correctly created i send it to myself as an attachment using the sendEmail function [5].

The other way is to store all the files in an array (messagesArray) and Fetch a Url of your server to send the array via POST. Using the UrlFetchApp.fetch() function in this case [6].

Here is the full code with both options:

```
function myeMailExportToEML() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:TestExportEML’);  
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
  Logger.log(threads)
  var messagesArray = []     

  for (var i=0; i< threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

      for (var j=0; j< messages.length; j++) {

        var myID = messages[j].getId();
        var msg = GmailApp.getMessageById(myID);
        var msgRaw = msg.getRawContent();

        var msgBlob = Utilities.newBlob(msgRaw, 'message/rfc822', 'example.eml');

        //Sends email with the .eml file attached
        GmailApp.sendEmail('RECIPIENT EMAIL', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.', {
          attachments: msgBlob,
          name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
        })   

    messagesArray.push(msgBlob);                          
      }
  }

    //make a post request to the server sending the .eml file in the request body(I didn't test this part)
   var formData = {
          'mail': messagesArray
   };
   var options = {
          'method' : 'post',
          'payload' : formData
        };
   UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://example.com/post', options);    
}
```

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getMessages()

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getRawContent()

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(String,String,String)

[5] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

[6] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer - you script is running perfect and send me a eMail with the EML-File. But where I can find the EML-File on my computer? My goal is to save the EML files.

Comment: Oh, i thought by "fileser" you meant file server. With the Blob you can upload the files to the Drive and download them from there. Other option is to zip all the blob files and send an email with this zipped blob, and download them from gmail. Check the zip() function: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#zip(BlobSource)

Comment: Hello, is is a little strange for me. I check It how can I bring a file into a blob. But how I can download the blob to e.g. my local HDD. Do you have a simply scriptexample for me?