# How do I get specific Gmail message parameters to be sent to a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, gmail-api

I checked out the following question which has an example relating Gmail and Google Sheets: [How to use Google App Scripts to retrieve Gmail emails in a customised way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832057/how-to-use-google-app-scripts-to-retrieve-gmail-emails-in-a-customised-way)

I'm wondering how I could add additional parameters: message date, sender email, message subject, full message body.

The problem with the above script is it retrieves the last email address from any thread in the inbox. I'm concerned with threads as well as individual messages.

Last, I'd love to add a clause that specifies to only grab message data for those messages that I've tagged in Gmail.

Here's some documentation on [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#parameters) and [Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/values#writing).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need here is Google Apps Script. So by checking the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/#methods_3), you can find the different methods that you can do in Gmail message.

For your question:

> How I could add additional parameters: message
>   date, [sender
>   email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getfrom),
>   [message
>   subject](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getsubject),
>   [full message
>   body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getbody).

As you can see in the above document. You will find here the method [getDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getdate) that will get the date and time of the message.

```
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // get first thread in inbox
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // get first message
Logger.log(message.getDate()); // log date and time of the message
```

Check the other link for some sample code of each parameter.

Also just check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) of AppScript on how to send this to a Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

For Question How I could add additional parameters: [message date](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getdate), [sender email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getfrom), [message subject](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getsubject), [full message body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getbody).
refer this documentation.

For App-script on how to send this to a Spreadsheet.
First create Spreadsheet in drive refer below code to add to it.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFilesByName('ADD NAME').next()).getSheets()[0]; ss.appendRow(["RESULT"])
```